# Example 2.3.4 in Hartshorne algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am reading Hartshorne algebraic geometry.

Example 2.3.4. Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and consider the *affine plane* over $k$, defined as $A^2_k = \text {Spec} k[x,y]$ . The closed points of $A^2_k$ are in one-to-one correspondence with ordered pairs of elements of $k$. Futhermore, the set of all closed points of $A^2_k$, with the induced topology, is homeomorphic to the *vareity* called $A^2$ in Chapter I. In addition to the closed points, there is a *generic point* $\xi$, corresponding to the zero ideal of $k[x,y]$, whose closure is the whole space. Also, for each irreducible polynomial $f(x,y)$, there is a point $\eta$ whose closure consists of $\eta$ together with all closed points $(a,b)$ for which $f(a,b)=0$. We say that $\eta$ is a *generic point* of the curve $f(x,y)=0$.

I cannot understand the sentence for $\eta$. Can $\eta$ be expressed explicitly?
I think $\eta$ work like $\xi$ for the set of all closed points of $A^2_k$.
I should be greatly indebted if you help me.

Comment: "Can η be expressed explicitly?" By definition points of $\mathbf A^2$ are prime ideals of $k[x,y]$. The point $\eta$ is the prime ideal generated by $f$. Is that the kind of answer you are looking for?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I expect $\eta$ is the prime ideal generated by $f$. If then how can we know this is the desired ons? To show this if $f(a,b)=0$, then $(x-a,y-b)$  should be in the closure of $\eta$. Right? How can I check this?

Comment: The definition of the Zariski topology says that $\overline{ \{ \eta \}}$ is the set of all prime ideals containing $f$. Do you see why $(x-a,y-b)$ contains $f$ whenever $f(a,b)=0$?

Comment: I have got the fact that " for $p \in \text{Spec} R$, $\overline { \{p\} }=V(p)$ "thanks to you. And reached to $\{\eta\} \cup \{(x-a,y-b) | f(a,b)=0\} \subset \overline {\{\eta\}}$. It remains that if $f \in p$, $p$ a prime ideal not $\eta$, then $p$ is of form $(x-a,y-b)$ for some $f(a,b)=0$. Can I have a hint?

Comment: The last thing is a consequence of the fact that $\mathbf A^2$ has dimension 2. By definition this means that the length of the longest possible chain of prime ideals in $k[x,y]$ is 2+1=3. So if we have a chain $(0) \subset (f) \subset (p)$, then $(p)$ cannot be strictly contained in a larger prime ideal. So $(p)$ must be maximal, and the nullstellensatz tells us what the maximal ideals in $k[x.y]$ look like.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I just understand fully. Thank you very much, sir.

Comment: You are welcome.